# Iframe still shows after redirect

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

In my classic asp application I have a page with 2 iframes.
leftframe has a searchbox. when a user enters something in the search box and press enter
its redircts the user to result page(Redirectpage.asp, which doesn't have any frames),
After redirecting to the Riderectpage.asp page, the rightFrame still exists in the page.
Any idea how to remove this rightframe.
We are using javascript for the redirect. here is my code.

```
<script>
    var ServerName = document.location.host;
    document.location.href ='http://' + ServerName + '/' + 'Redirectpage.asp)
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect the outer frame by setting `top.location`